# pointing external domain to subdomain

Tags: php, apache, dns

What I try to achive is a simple domain pointing to example I have

```
www.domain.tdl
```

and supply to the users

```
username.domain.tdl
```

which works great.

But as soon as I want to enable a domain pointing (they create a CNAME entry on there own domain to the subdomain) I would have to setup a record for each domain in the webserver and restart it after.

How would I achieve such a construct with Apache?
And what's the best way of doing that?

The best example for that is probably Google Mail: you can get mail.yourdomain.tl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a domain points to it which isn't defined in the vhosts it will automatically use the first vhost.

So if you make sure the website is the first vhost it will automically work.

Comment: the problem is the username .. > its for whitelabeling ..

i know it takes the default url but the problem is the related username to that domain ..

Comment: Is there a reason why you cannot use PHP for displaying the right stuff (or disallowing access if username doesn't exists) based on the username in the domain? Look at the `$_SERVER` superglobal.

Comment: @PeeHaa I agree with PeeHaa, use PHP to display the right content.

Answer (score 0):

You can use some bash/sh script to add new part/extend your apache2.conf or vhosts.conf if I understood you correctly.

Comment: IMHO a bad idea, because you need to have lots of confidence in your script, your script needs access to sensitive files, and you'll have to reload the apache config all the time.

Comment: If something needs a lot of confidence it should not be written or what? where's logic?

Comment: If you can avoid open-heart surgery, you should. That's what I meant.

Answer (score 0):

Just have your Apache answer to everything and do not restrict it by domain. Be sure that this vhost is the first one to be loaded on this server. You can achieve this by naming it, e.g. `/etc/apache2/sites-available/0001-myservice`.

Answer (score 0):

There are another possible option: [configure vhost with wildcard subdomain](http://steinsoft.net/index.php?site=programming/articles/apachewildcarddomain). Just alike:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /www/subdomain
    ServerName www.domain.tld
    ServerAlias *.domain.tld
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: This is not an answer to his question.

Comment: the setup of the subdomain was no the problem .. more like pointing a external domain into .. on top of that subdomain .. so apache realise it its realted to that domain .. i endet up getting a own ip adress and use a similar construct as fallback .. via PHP i get the hostname and check it against the database